# Is it better to load data from database at mainform?

Tags: c#, winforms, performance, linq

I am working on an application that uses same list of data in multi-children forms, but I noticed that when I child form it has some delay before showing.
By the way I am using linq to grab data from database.

So, my question is that is it better to grab data when main form loads and pass it to other forms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A serious drawback to loading data initially, for example while displaying the spash screen, is that you have to worry about whether the data gets changed.  For example UserA may start the app and load 10 records from the underlying table.  Then UserB inserts a record into the underlying table.  You need to devise a way for the app to check for new records each time UserA loads the other forms.

As mentioned by @JonKoivula, it's better to load the data in the background and not block the UI thread.  You might display a "spinner" or something to entertain the user while data is loading.  It's been my experience that users understand "spinners" and truly believe that they indicate work is actually happening.

Comment: Went all through loading data using async initially. Thanks for the help guys.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. But do it in the background so it does not block UI thread. For example async / await(asynchoronous code) is good choice of querying data from database, because it will not block thread.

Comment: How can you say that? Never learned that there can be a business layer that is independent of the UI? The answer here should be "no, that should not be in a form at all".

Comment: @JonKoivula Okey thank you for advice, I'll try that later on, and sorry if my question is dumb, I am new to windows forms.

Comment: While it's better to use a Business Logic Layer as mentioned by TomTom, but in the case It doesn't make any difference if you use a BLL or not; if you are doing a blocking task in UI thread, it make the UI frozen. So it's better to load data in a different thread. You can use async/await pattern as mentioned by Jon or use BackgroundWorker or use a thread. By the way, neither the question nor the answer is dumb.

Comment: @RezaAghaei what I actually thought about is grabbing the data on splash screen before the main UI shows up using asynctask. Thank you.

Comment: @ConvictMoody You are welcome:)